# Carousel not working when window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of 3 divs floating to the left in a straight line. Each div is the width of the page.
Here's the HTML structure;

```
<div class="Horizontal-Wrapper">
      <div class="Horizontal-Section">
        <div class="Project-Wrapper">
          <div class="Project-Box" id="PJB1"><div class="Project-Box-Overlay"><h2>Splash</h2><p>Industries define the ideal selection for both wholesale and retail quantities of high quality</p></div></div>
          <div class="Project-Box" id="PJB2"><div class="Project-Box-Overlay"><h2>Splash</h2><p>Industries define the ideal selection for both wholesale and retail quantities of high quality</p></div></div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="Horizontal-Section">
        <div class="Project-Wrapper">
          <div class="Project-Box" id="PJB3"><div class="Project-Box-Overlay"><h2>Splash</h2><p>Industries define the ideal selection for both wholesale and retail quantities of high quality</p></div></div>
          <div class="Project-Box" id="PJB4"><div class="Project-Box-Overlay"><h2>Splash</h2><p>Industries define the ideal selection for both wholesale and retail quantities of high quality</p></div></div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="Horizontal-Section">
        <div class="Project-Wrapper">
          <div class="Project-Box" id="PJB5"><div class="Project-Box-Overlay"><h2>Splash</h2><p>Industries define the ideal selection for both wholesale and retail quantities of high quality</p></div></div>
          <div class="Project-Box" id="PJB6"><div class="Project-Box-Overlay"><h2>Splash</h2><p>Industries define the ideal selection for both wholesale and retail quantities of high quality</p></div></div>          
        </div>
       </div>        
     </div>
```

So on button click it should move the next div. I've accomplished this by using the following script;

```
   var inner_width = $('body').innerWidth();
   $('#next').on('click', function () {
      $('.Horizontal-Section').animate({'left': 'inner_width' +'px'});
   });
```

The problem i'm facing is that the scrolling is messed up when the browser is resized since i cant get the proper width of the page.

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: // Returns width of browser viewport  
`$( window ).width();`

Comment: I couldn't save it since i undid everything and tried a different approach that didn't work out.

Comment: Well, provide a jsfiddle... I'd recommend using an existing plugin, why invent stuff that has already been done to death, find a good plugin that will also provide extra features that might be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from not rechecking the width of the browser more than once. It checks on page load and then sets your variable to that.

Try this:

```
var inner_width = $('body').innerWidth();
$(window).resize(function() {
  inner_width = $('body').innerWidth();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! I'll post my working script in a while!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change inner_width on resize and reposition the elements.

I am assuming .Horizontal-Section has 100% width set in CSS.

```
var inner_width = $('body').innerWidth();

$('#next').on('click', function () {
    $('.Horizontal-Section').animate({'left': inner_width +'px'});
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    inner_width = $('body').innerWidth();
    $('.Horizontal-Section').css({'left': inner_width +'px'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your working code within a function and call that function on `(document).ready();` and `(window).resize();`

checkout following code

**JS**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(func_name);
 $(window).resize(func_name);

 function func_name(){
  var inner_width = $('body').innerWidth();
   $('#next').on('click', function () {
      $('.Horizontal-Section').animate({'left': 'inner_width' +'px'});
   });
 }
</script>
```